# How can I convert screen coordinatess to world coordinates in OpenTK?

Tags: c#, mouse, opentk

I'm making a windows forms application with opengl view. I need to get the mouse coords converted to the opengl world coords. Well, my Y coord gets converted wrong. It's hard to explain, so here is the video:
http://tinypic.com/r/23sal8k/6. I'm constantly pressing left mouse button and the red dot should be where the mouse is(but it isn't). Here is the code:

```
    private void glview_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Point worldCoords = convertScreenToWorldCoords(e.X, e.Y);
            shitx = worldCoords.X;
            shity = worldCoords.Y;
        }
    }


    // functions:
    public static Point convertScreenToWorldCoords(int x, int y)
    {
        int[] viewport = new int[4];
        Matrix4 modelViewMatrix, projectionMatrix;
        GL.GetFloat(GetPName.ModelviewMatrix, out modelViewMatrix);
        GL.GetFloat(GetPName.ProjectionMatrix, out projectionMatrix);
        GL.GetInteger(GetPName.Viewport, viewport);
        Vector2 mouse;
        mouse.X = x;
        mouse.Y = viewport[3] - y;
        Vector4 vector = UnProject(ref projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix, new Size(viewport[2], viewport[3]), mouse);
        Point coords = new Point((int)vector.X, (int)vector.Y);
        return coords;
    }
    public static Vector4 UnProject(ref Matrix4 projection, Matrix4 view, Size viewport, Vector2 mouse)
    {
        Vector4 vec;

        vec.X = 2.0f * mouse.X / (float)viewport.Width - 1;
        vec.Y = -(2.0f * mouse.Y / (float)viewport.Height - 1);
        vec.Z = 0;
        vec.W = 1.0f;

        Matrix4 viewInv = Matrix4.Invert(view);
        Matrix4 projInv = Matrix4.Invert(projection);

        Vector4.Transform(ref vec, ref projInv, out vec);
        Vector4.Transform(ref vec, ref viewInv, out vec);

        if (vec.W > float.Epsilon || vec.W < float.Epsilon)
        {
            vec.X /= vec.W;
            vec.Y /= vec.W;
            vec.Z /= vec.W;
        }

        return vec;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got this fixed. I just changed

```
mouse.Y = viewport[3] - y;
```

to

```
mouse.Y = y + (ClientRectangle.Height - glview.Size.Height);
```

still not very accurate but not very bad.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem and have used your code. 
I think I fixed it fully now.

```
in ConvertScreenToWorld()
change 
mouse.Y = viewport[3] - y;
to
mouse.Y = y;

in UnProject()
change
vec.Y = -(2.0f * mouse.Y / (float)viewport.Height - 1);
to
vec.Y = 2.0f * mouse.Y / (float)viewport.Height - 1;
```

then 
call it like 
convertScreenToWorldCoords(e.X,ClientRectangle.Height - e.Y);

it's very precise too
bye!

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
-(vec.Y = 2.0f * mouse.Y / (float)viewport.Height) - 1;
```

to

```
-(vec.Y = 2.0f * mouse.Y / (float)viewport.Height) + 1;
```

and it works.